How can I map camera up/down in World of Warcraft in an Accessible Way?
With World of Warcraft being released on nVidia GEForce NOW, and my own ownership of a Steam Deck, I've begun mapping all of the Mouse/WASD controls to the steam deck. Fortunately, Steam has robust controller mapping on the deck.
I've been pretty successful, except for one thing -  I'm looking to map the "Pan up" and "pan down" of character perspective.
So far, I've been able to do a combo with the joystick. Moving the right joystick up performs a combo of

Left click
Move mouse to relative position (after some tweaking, +25 and -25 pixels seem to be a sweet spot)
Enable turbo - at most I can repeat every "10", which I imagine to be 10ms. This is the highest frequency available.

The problem here is, this is choppy. I also worry that rapid-repeat click drags to consistent areas may get my account bot-flagged.
Is there an official option from World of Warcaft for non-mouse users? They've implemented a lot of functionality since I "quit" 5 years ago. . . Including an "Interact" keybind that has been helpful.
Alternatively, is there a mapping option within the Steam Deck I may not be thinking of to emulate this input?
I'd like to avoid solutions that use AddOns, because they would not be practical with the platform I am using to play.
For those curious as to why I want to play WoW on a Steam Deck, I just want to chase achievements and farm. My raiding days are behind me.

Left and Right are easily done with "character rotate", which are "A" and "D" by default. Up and down are another story.

By the way, you can run WoW through Proton on the Steam Deck, you don't have to run it through GeForce NOW. I love playing WoW on the Steam Deck!

@Kidburla I was doing that for a while but the patches were a real pain!

It turns out, you can change the entire "Joystick" characteristic.
I had the joystick set to "Directional Pad", which is why I had to macro mouse movements to it.
You can change the joystick to a "Joystick Mouse", which solves all of my issues after you map "Hold right click" to the joystick as well.
I will update this answer with pictures when I have the chance.
